# Can one export spices and teff flour from Ethiopia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, ethiopia

Ethiopian cuisine has some unique spices and grains. I've heard that there used to be a restriction on exporting teff to control supply. I'd like to buy teff flour and berbere, and other spices. Will I have any problems?

Comment: You also need to check the legality of importing raw foodstuffs into your home country.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There don't seem to be any restrictions, except that berbere (and perhaps other spices) are not allowed in *hand luggage* at Bole International Airport (and perhaps other Ethiopian airports) but are allowed in checked luggage.

I was told that it is difficult to buy small quantities (< 25 kg) of teff flour, but found a mill that was willing to sell a couple kilos for 17 birr/kg.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sign at the security control at the departure gates at Bole Airport that says "berbere (cultural spices)" is not allowed in hand luggage. So it seems that in addition to berbere, mitmita etc would not be allowed. I cannot find the reason for this, but would be interested to know.

Comment: Only "hand luggage"? Does that mean you can check it in?

Comment: @Berwyn: yes, as I said in my answer. I'm not sure what this answer adds.

Comment: Sorry @Max I only noticed Jonathan's answer since it was new. Indeed, is more of a comment given your answer.

Comment: Perhaps berbere is prohibited in the cabin because if it spills, it can be an irritant? Although I have never seen cayenne pepper prohibited.